# How to manually view the webpage before the tests run in cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a webpage in which i want to test all the data and the top results, but before i am able to do that i am required to authenticate via a phone. The main problem is that I have to prove that i am not a robot via a captcha and also authenticate the phone with a phone call. All of this, as i believe, is done manually (we can't remove the captcha or the phone verification from the test process). How do I first without the help of cypress login, and then set up all the tests?

I had tried to login in between the tests, yet they couldn't continue after my interaction.

Answer (score 0):

All such login procedures should be disabled *on test environments.* Simply because you have no control over them. The only result of trying to work around such GUI authentication schemes is you will make your tests flaky. Not even mentioning problems with different domains in Cypress.

If there is such an authentication, it's much better to use an API, e.g. like described [here for Auth0](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/testing-strategies/auth0-authentication). But that requires some setup in Auth0, and then some Cypress code.